# show() and hide() functions are not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make the button with the ID `back` to show only when the user gets an error message, the problem is that the error message shows without any kind of problem but the button isn't.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
 var button = $('#back');
 button.hide("fast");
 button.click(function(){
    $('#form').show();
    $("#result").hide();
    button.hide();
    });     
 $("#pgform").submit(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();     
    var nome = $('input[name= Nome]').val();
    var cognome = $('input[name= Cognome]').val();
    var background = $('#bktx').val();      
    var post_data = {'nome': nome,'cognome' : cognome,'background': background};        
    $.post('crea_pg_db.php',post_data,function(response){
        if(response.type =='error'){
            $("#result").addClass('failed');
            var output = "<strong>"+response.text +"</strong>";
            button.show();
        }
        else {
            $("#result").addClass('success');
            var output = "<strong>"+response.text+"<br /> Nome : </strong>"+ nome +"<br /> <strong>Cognome : </strong>"+cognome;                
        }           
        $('#form').hide();
        $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();           
    },'json');   
}); // end submit function
});//end document ready
```

## Edit

I've found the solution to the problem.

The function `.html(output)` replaces everything that was in `#result`, it was replacing the button code too, that's why it was not working, I've changed the code and now everything works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 event.preventDefault();
 var status;     
 var nome = $('input[name= Nome]').val();
 var cognome = $('input[name= Cognome]').val();
 var background = $('#bktx').val();
 var post_data = {'nome': nome,'cognome' : cognome,'background': background};
 $.post('crea_pg_db.php',post_data,function(response){
    if(response.type =='error'){
        $("#result").addClass('failed');
        var output = "<strong>"+response.text +"</strong> <button id='back'>Indietro</button>";
        status = 1;
    }else{
        $("#result").addClass('success');
        var output = "<strong>"+response.text+"<br /> Nome : </strong>"+ nome +"<br /> <strong>Cognome : </strong>"+cognome;
    }
    $('#form').hide();
    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
    if(status == 1){
         var button = $('#back');
         button.click(function(){
            $('#form').show();
            $("#result").hide();
            button.hide();
        });
    }   
    },'json');
 }); // end submit function
});//end document ready
```

Comment: If you mean the html page, i dont think it's necessary, because everthing works fine there, is just the show / hide that dont work, anyray the button is inside this : <div id="result"><button id='back'>Back</button></div>

Comment: since you've found the answer, post it as an answer! You can answer your own question. it will be a lot less confusing than having it inline with your question.

Comment: providing an answer within a question is very confusing

Comment: instead of `$("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();` in the original code, `$("#result").hide().append(output).slideDown();` or `$("#result").hide().prepend(output).slideDown();` would add the message without overriding the button.

Answer (score 0):

The OP found a solution [to their problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218832/show-and-hide-functions-are-not-working):

> I've found the solution to the problem.
>
> The function `.html(output)` replaces everything that was in `#result`, it was replacing the button code too, that's why it was not working, I've changed the code and now everything works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 event.preventDefault();
 var status;     
 var nome = $('input[name= Nome]').val();
 var cognome = $('input[name= Cognome]').val();
 var background = $('#bktx').val();
 var post_data = {'nome': nome,'cognome' : cognome,'background': background};
 $.post('crea_pg_db.php',post_data,function(response){
    if(response.type =='error'){
        $("#result").addClass('failed');
        var output = "<strong>"+response.text +"</strong> <button id='back'>Indietro</button>";
        status = 1;
    }else{
        $("#result").addClass('success');
        var output = "<strong>"+response.text+"<br /> Nome : </strong>"+ nome +"<br /> <strong>Cognome : </strong>"+cognome;
    }
    $('#form').hide();
    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
    if(status == 1){
         var button = $('#back');
         button.click(function(){
            $('#form').show();
            $("#result").hide();
            button.hide();
        });
    }   
    },'json');
 }); // end submit function
});//end document ready
```